# telnet fails to re-connect when the telnet session is exited without gracefully?

Tags: linux, telnet

I had a telnet session to my embedded box, which is running telnet server.
From my embedded box, I did another telnet to another session of shell.

Now, when I have closed the linux terminal window (without gracefully), I see that I cannot reconnect to my embedded box.

I get the following error -

```
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I checked the /var/log/messages -

when I have exited gracefully - I get the message - telnet exit

If I don't gracefully, I get the message - user logged out.
When I try to login again, I don't see any error messages on
/var/log/secure, /var/log/messages